# How to disable remote desktop debugging of WebView2 in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, webview2

I have an application written in C# winform in which I use webview2. When you activate Remote Debugging mode, all content can be accessed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/remote-debugging/windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/remote-debugging-desktop

It means that by opening Chrome and Edge browser on the device where the app is installed, you can find the list of web pages or apps with web views by going to edge://inspect or chrome://inspect, click inspect and see the HTML, JS and other resources of the apps. This is a useful feature in the development environment, but I want to turn it off after publishing.

To be able to turn this off, I checked if developer mode was on. I tried deleting the file created via regedit for Edge but somehow it still works.

Is there a way to definitively turn this feature off?